# How is のに used in this sentence?

Tags: particle-に, particle-の

> 順番違うよ

> やってるのに順番もくそもないけど

My understanding is that he's saying "the order is wrong"but then he correct himself and says "since I'm already dong at this point the order doesn't matter much"

Why is のに being used here?

Comment: Can you add a little more context? What is he doing and what order is he talking about?

Answer (score 0):

のに here is not being used in the adversative sense, 'although...', but as the dative of a simple nominalization of やっている 'in the act if doing', 'it's nonsense to talk about an order in doing [this].'

Comment: I need more context to completely rule out this possibility but you would more likely say やるのに順番もくそもないけど if that's what you mean.

Comment: @aguijonazo That had occurred to me as well but certainly context is necessary.

Comment: He's talking about dating. He's going out with the girl but they haven't even kissed yet. Now she asked for a kiss and he wonders about it given the "order" is wrong (They already dating and sleeping together but they never kissed).

Comment: In that case I would have to admit that the のに here is simply adversative.